# Arranging div boxes inside another div box to be flexible for small and large screen widths

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a feature to allow users to drag div boxes around and then update the database with the style so when they come back to the page it remembers their positioning and places the boxes in the right spot (relative to the parent div).

I currently have this working, however, if the user positions the boxes using a screen width of say 1600px and then opens the page on say their iPad or a smaller screen size of say 1000px then the boxes dissapear if they are positioned too close to the parent border.

I need some help figuring out how to arrange div boxes inside the parent, but make it so its flexible when they go to a different screen size the boxes will still be there.

I created a jsfiddle to simulate the situation.

[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/VN4hw/)

HTML COde:

```
<div id="dashboard_wrapper">
  <div class="ui-corner-all border_all_grey dashboard_widget drag_drop">
    Box 1
  </div>
  <div class="ui-corner-all border_all_grey dashboard_widget drag_drop">
    Box 2
  </div>               
</div>
<div id="box_positions"></div>
```

and JS Code:

```
$(".drag_drop, .drag_drop_chart").resizable();
$(".drag_drop, .drag_drop_chart").draggable({
    start: function( event, ui ) {$(this).trigger("click")},
    stop: function ( event, ui ) {
        var position = $(this).position();
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var top = position.top;
        var left = position.left;
        var max_top = 0;

        if(top < 0){ $(this).css({"top":1}); }
        if(left < 0){ $(this).css({"left":1}); }                                    
        if(top > 800){ $(this).css({"top":800}); }

        $(".drag_drop, .drag_drop_chart").each(function() {
            //Find the box with the largest "top" value
            var x_top = $(this).position().top;
            if(max_top < x_top){ max_top = x_top; }
        });

        var height = max_top + 280;
        $("#dashboard_wrapper").css({"height":height});

        var style = $(this).attr("style");
        var box = $(this).text();
        $("#box_positions").append(box + ": style=" + style + "<br/>");
    }
});

var boxes = $(".drag_drop, .drag_drop_chart");

// Set up click handlers for each box
boxes.click(function() {

    var el = $(this), // The box that was clicked
    max = 0;

    // Find the highest z-index
    boxes.each(function() {
        // Find the current z-index value
        var z = parseInt( $( this ).css( "z-index" ), 10 );
        if ( isNaN(z) ){ z = 1; }

        // Keep either the current max, or the current z-index, whichever is higher
        max = Math.max( max, z );
    });

    // Set the box that was clicked to the highest z-index plus one
    el.css("z-index", max + 1 );
});
```

Any help and ideas will be appreciated.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the current resolution when you open the page.

Move left any of the boxes positioned out of the visible area.

Check that using Box Left Position plus Box Width.

For example, if a Box is 200px width, and it is 900px Left, it ends at 1100px.

If you are now at 1000px resolution, you can move it left of the (maximum screen resolution - box's width), then left = (1000px - 200px) =  800px.

Comment: You are welcome; KISS principle ftw! :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle